# Why can't I get to mouse click count == 2 first in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, click-counting

In my Java Swing app, I have a JList, and when I double click on an item in the list, it always does click count == 1 things first then do things in click count == 2, why ?

```
 list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
 {
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
   {
     if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
     {
       if (e.getClickCount()==1) Out("Left-ClickCount()==1");
       else if (e.getClickCount()==2) Out("Left-ClickCount()==2");     
     }
     else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
     {
       if (e.getClickCount()==2) Out("Right-ClickCount()==2");
       else if (e.getClickCount()==1) Out("Right-ClickCount()==1");
     }
   }
 });
```

No matter how fast I click, I intentionally put "if (e.getClickCount()==2)" before "else if (e.getClickCount()==1)", it still catches ClickCount==1 first ? Why ? How to fix it ?

Comment: That's the way it works. Normally the first click is to select the row for processing and the double click is to perform some Action on that row. This is not a Java thing. This is standard application design, that is, a double click should only work on a item that has first been selected. Clicking the mouse fast just increments the click count every time. It does not wait until you stop clicking and then determine if it was a single, double or triple click.

Comment: @camickr It's also a JList thing. Other components don't eat mouseclicks like that. If you disable the JList cells to be uneditable, the double-clicking works as OP expects.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster, This Is not JList specific. JList is not editable. I think you mean JTable.  In any case JTable works the same as a JList. If the table is NOT editable, you can keep clicking and the click count will keep increasing. The difference is that when a table IS editable, you only get single and double clicks and then the editor is invoked so future clicks will be on the editor, not the table. The point is you will always get a single click before a double click, which is the way is should be.

Comment: If so, how to design my app so that a single right mouse click plays the mp3 file, but a double right mouse click opens the mp3 file for editing ?

Comment: Take a look at the music player on your system. The standard design I usually see is that a single click (or up/down key on the keyboard) will select a song. Then a double click (or using Enter on the keyboard) will play the song. Don't forget a proper GUI design should allow you to use a mouse or the keyboard. Then to edit you would use a right click to popup a menu of options for that song.

Comment: @camickr you are right, I was confused with JTable. Time for bed.

Comment: @camickr, thanks, I thought of using the enter key too, that's a possible solution, but this Java double click behavior doesn't see like a standard behavior I'd expect compared to other programs, a double click is a "Double-click" within a time frame, like half a second, it shouldn't be combined with a single click, am I not right on this ?

Comment: `am I not right on this ?` - I already stated you are NOT right. When you click the mouse twice you will generate two MouseEvents. You always get a single click event, the only question is whether the second click generates a double click (if within the time frame) or a second single click (if not within the time frame).

Comment: @camickr What I meat was : the behavior Java now has doesn't fit with what user would expect in the current world compared to other programs, now it's like a switch statement without breaks, falls through all cases, and the second click should generate a double click and be able to let user adjust the time frame : 0.25 sec, 0.5 sec... [ so my AM I not right was towards this issue ]

Comment: @frank, The Java behaviour is the real world behaviour. Two mouse clicks generate two events. This is how real world programs work. Try using your word processor. Try doing a slow double click. The first click sets the caret to where you click. The second click then highlights the word. Try the same test on your File Explorer. The first click selects the file and the second click edits the file. You can't have a double click without first having a single click at the same time. Maybe I'm missing what you are saying, I can't explain myself any better.

Comment: The time frame which determines whether you get a single and a double click event, or two single click events is controlled by the OS. In Windows you can go to the Conrol Panel and select Mouse and the select the first "Buttons" tabs where you can set the double click speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after some Goggling and my own enhancement, here is the code that works to my original expectations :

```
  boolean isAlreadyOneClick=false;
...
    DefaultListModel xlistModel=new DefaultListModel();
    JList xlist=new JList(xlistModel);
    xlist.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
      {
        int index=xlist.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
        String item=xlistModel.getElementAt(index).toString();

        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
        {
          if (isAlreadyOneClick)
          {
            System.out.println("Left double click : "+item);
            isAlreadyOneClick=false;
          }
          else
          {
            isAlreadyOneClick=true;
            Timer t=new Timer("doubleclickTimer",false);
            t.schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
              @Override
              public void run()
              {
                if (isAlreadyOneClick) System.out.println("Left single click : "+item);
                isAlreadyOneClick=false;
              }
            },250);
          }              
        }
        else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
        {
          if (isAlreadyOneClick)
          {
            System.out.println("Right double click : "+item);
            isAlreadyOneClick=false;
          }
          else
          {
            isAlreadyOneClick=true;
            Timer t=new Timer("doubleclickTimer",false);
            t.schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
              @Override
              public void run()
              {
                if (isAlreadyOneClick) System.out.println("Right single click : "+item);
                isAlreadyOneClick=false;
              }
            },250);
          }
        }
      }
    });

    xlistModel.addElement("123");
    xlistModel.addElement("abc");
    JFrame f=new JFrame("Test Clicks");
    f.add(xlist);
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) { } });
    f.setBackground(SystemColor.control);

    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
```